# Stylesheets load ok but no CSS

Tags: html, css, http, stylesheet

Take a look here: http://ec2-122-248-199-2.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

The stylesheets seem to load ok, but they are not having any effect on the page.  I cannot figure out why.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your stylesheets dont have any rules in them

Comment: ah so you're seeing blank stylesheets?  That could be a clue.

Comment: I saw blank stylesheets in firebug but when i went directly to the url they were there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP server claims the css files are written in `text/plain` instead of `text/css`.

```
quentin@system:~ # curl -I http://ec2-122-248-199-2.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/stylesheets/layout.css | grep -i content-type
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Comment: Aaah hmmm so my web server is not serving the correct MIME type.  That's a huge clue.. Thanks very much